# Remove Permanent URL for custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types

I have created a dynamic slider and using custom post type and featured images to upload slider's images. What I want to do is to remove Permanant URL for my custom post type i.e. post is not accessible with its permanent URL nor it will appear under title while adding custom post. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work, you'll probably need to set multiple arguments to get exactly the way you want. In situations like this, I usually start by settings the `public` argument to false and then adding in everything that I do want displayed.

In this case, setting `public` to false also sets `publicly_queryable` to `false` as well as `exclude_from_search` to `true`, both of which it sounds like you want.

I don't know that you can remove the permalink from displaying beneath the title, but you could easily enqueue a stylesheet on the admin that hides the field.